# Secure Boot and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, secure-boot

I have researched the topic of Secure Boot and how hibernation has been disabled as a result, on this forum.

However, I have read elsewhere that compiling your own kernel with a patch could enable hibernation. Could someone provide guidance on how to do this? I was unable to find anything specific.

Incidentally, is the issue that hibernation images cannot be self signed which means they will be loaded regardless of the keys being used by Secure Boot?

Answer (score 3):

I subsequently found out that hibernation with Secure Boot is disabled as a result of Lockdown - how pertinent it is to be writing that right now.

In Ubuntu 20.04, Lockdown can no longer be disabled using Alt+SysRq+X.

As I am loading my Secure Boot keys using UEFI Secure Boot (via KeyTool.efi) rather than MOK Manager, all that is required is to disable **Secure MOK Boot** (rather than UEFI Secure Boot) using the command:

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

Run the command and create a password. Restart and then run MOK Manager (mmx64.efi). Disable Secure Boot and Lockdown is disabled, enabling hibernation. Note, it is safe for me to do so because I am using LUKS but otherwise this is not advised.

Note, in order to execute mmx64.efi, it must be signed using your Secure Boot key. The article at https://github.com/jiazhang0/meta-secure-core/blob/master/meta-efi-secure-boot/README.md I found particularly useful.